# any known universality results of random matrices with non-independent entries?

Tags: random-matrices

GUE, GOE, hermitian/symmetric wigner matrices, ... already known with some mild assumptions.
but is there any this kind of results without independent entries condition. thanks a lot.

Comment: I would have thought that even a little searching on this topic would have brought up some examples. For instance, hermitian matrices where the joint density function of the entries is invariant under conjugation by unitaries - doesn't this get discussed in Mehta's book and other sources?

Comment: as currently stated, the question reads a bit like a "fishing expedition". It might help people give useful answers if you can give some indication of what you've already seen and where you've tried looking.

Answer (score 4):

Another example is the adjacency matrix of a random regular graph. Here the entries are $0,1$ but the row sums and column sums must all be equal. For some properties of this matrix, see 
 http://arxiv.org/pdf/1011.6646.pdf

Comment: To add to this:  The largest eigenvalue is governed by the Tracy Widom distribution (GOE).  See http://arxiv.org/PS_cache/arxiv/pdf/0903/0903.4295v5.pdf

Answer (score 2):

Of course there is:

For example: [this paper](http://people.math.gatech.edu/~lubinsky/Research%20papers/UniversBulkJan07.pdf) by Lubinsky describes universality for a special class of tridiginal matrices. For example the condition off-diagonals $\equiv 1$ and entries on the diagonal are in $\ell^1(\mathbb{Z})$ would suffice. So the matrices are
$$
 H_N = \begin{pmatrix} b_1 & 1 &  \\\
 1 & b_2 & 1 & \\\
 & 1 & b_3 &1 &  \\\
 & & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots \\\
 & & & 1 & b_N \end{pmatrix}
$$
with $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} |b_n| < \infty$.

This can be further generalized see: Avila--Last--Simon. Of course all these results are for special tridiagonal matrices (Jacobi operators).

Last, there is also the work by Deift et al. See the [book](http://books.google.com/books?id=SBR8yv0LkFgC&pg=PA237&dq=deift+universality&hl=en&ei=eMkvTJz7K4_csAag26y2Ag&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=4&ved=0CDsQ6AEwAw#v=onepage&q=deift%20universality&f=false).

Answer (score 1):

the classic example is Dyson's circular ensemble of random unitary matrices (distributed uniformly with respect to the Haar measure); in the limit of large matrix size the correlation function of the eigenvalues tends to a universal limit.

Answer (score 1):

There are results on  symmetric Gaussian matrices where  the entries are dependent but the depedencies become weaker  and weaker as  the  size of the matrix grows.

See e.g. http://arxiv.org/pdf/0707.2333.pdf and the references therein.